# How can I be certain I only delete my local branch in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

Let us suppose I have developed a cool feature and pushed the branch `my-cool-feature`. I am sure all is ok and I do not need it anymore locally, because the branch will be merged into `master`.

Using `git branch -d my-cool-feature` throws some error message `If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D my-cool-feature'`.

Would the use of the "-D" flag delete the branch remotely too or *only* locally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+branch+locally+remote

Comment: Except for `git fetch`, which calls up another Git to *get* stuff from them, and `git push`, which calls up another Git to *give* stuff to them and/or make changes to their branch and tag names and such, *everything* you do in Git works locally. (Remember that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.* The fetch uses another Git; the second command works locally.)

Comment: Your local Git holds *your* branches. The other Git you fetch from (with `git pull`) or send stuff to (`git push`) has *its* branches. Their branches aren't yours, nor vice versa. You just like to *sync* with them now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `git branch -D branch-name` will delete branch only locally

Comment: `git push --delete`

Answer (score 1):

`git branch -D <branch-name>` only deletes local branch.

To delete a branch from remote, there is a different command.

`git push origin --delete <branch-name>`

follow this link.
https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/delete-remote-branch

Comment: What if I later I change my mind and want to pull it from remote? How do I do that? Using `git fetch --all` does not seem to work.

Comment: If you have not deleted the branch from remote , then just simply do 

`git checkout -b <branch-name>` it should restore that branch

Comment: If I  `git checkout -b <branch-name>` I get a `There is no tracking information for the current branch` message.

Comment: check if that branch exist on remote. 
Switch to master branch and try checkout.

Comment: If you have branch remotly and don't have locally, you can invoke git pull --all, so you get all branches and just can git ch branch-name

Comment: I always prefer `git fetch origin` rather than `git pull --all` for these kind of issues, as "fetch" only downloads data from a remote repository and does not try to integrate it on your files.